# How to show Text in the text file separated by commas in a DataRow or a GridView in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

I have created an application in C#. I want to display the text in the text file separated by commas in a DataRow or a GridView.

I am using this code to display the text in a listbox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = File.OpenText("C:\\File.txt"); 
    string line;
    bool flag = true;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(new { srno= line, Date= "descr", Time= DateTime.Now ,symbol = Symbol  });
    }
}
```

But its not well for others to understand what its displaying.i want to display something like this

check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEmdz.jpg

There would be great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Have you met [Mr. String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)?

Comment: ya i know split method but how can i display the words in a gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Silly me** looks like this is WinForms not asp.net. Got retagged. I'll leave this here for someone else then.

You'll want to turn the file in to a `DataTable`. There is a decent example of this at http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/256-csv-datatable.html

It's more of a generic approach than anything.

Here is an untested example you could try to work through.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Srno");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Date");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Time");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Symbol");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
    string[] s =  line.Split(',');
    row["Srno"] = s[0];
    row["Date"] = s[1];
    row["Time"] = s[2];
    row["Symbol"] = s[3];
}

//Add to your GridView that is in your aspx file
gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Probably not. You retagged it as Winforms after I posted .

Comment: Its not me But i am really sorry can u pls give me the code for winforms

Comment: Try switching it to DataGridView for WinForms. I don't know Winforms very well. unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Define a class (say `Foo`) having four public `properties` - srno, Date,Time, and symbol. Use `String.Split` method to parse the comma separated string, constructs an object of Foo class and append it to `List<Foo>`. Finally bind the `List<Foo>` object to the `GridView` control.

Demo:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string SrNo {get;set;}
  public string Date {get;set;}
  public string Time {get;set;}
  public string Symbol {get;set;}
}

List<Foo> list=new List<Foo>();

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string []ar = line.Split(',');
    list.Add(new Foo()
       {
         SrNo=ar[0],
         Date=ar[1],
         Time=ar[2],
         Symbol=ar[3]
       });
}
//Bind the list
dataGridView1.DataSource=list;
```

Comment: @GmBasha - Is this web app or winform?